# insertBefore attaching element only at the last element of a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of rows where I want to add another set of rows. I'm trying to do it as loop all the rows and then on each row I did `insertAfter` operation.

```
let rows_to_be_attached = parent_tr.nextAll().not('.newly-rows');
let rows_to_attach = parent_tr.nextAll('tr.newly-rows').not('.mia');

$(rows_to_be_attached).each(function(i, el) {    
  $(rows_to_attach).insertAfter($(el));    
}
```

It only attached the `rows_to_attach` 'tr's' at the last `el`. Why?

Comment: where is `added_rows` in your code ?

Comment: You're moving the same `added_rows` element in every iteration of the loop. You may need a `clone()` call here, depending on exactly what it is that you're trying to achieve. Also note that you're double-wrapping a couple of your jQuery objects here, and you can just pass `el` to `insertAfter()` without making it in to a jQuery object

Comment: @PranavCBalan `rows_to_attach`.. sorry made changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting the same element on each loop so it will move from the previously inserted place in DOM instead of that clone and insert it.

```
$(rows_to_be_attached).each(function(i , el){    
    added_rows.clone().insertAfter($(el));    
})
```

---

If there is multiple and you want to insert one by one then use the index to get the element.

```
$(rows_to_be_attached).each(function(i , el){    
    added_rows.eq(i).insertAfter($(el));    
})
```

Comment: What is clone exactly doing here?... on a loop it moves the inserted element? so we are cloning when its inserted ?

Comment: @ReyYoung :  can you make your requiremenet a bit more clear

Comment: no sir. you've already helped me... just waiting to make it correct answer.. cannot accept answer within 7 min.. anyway can you still help me with another question? I will ask and mention it here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572720/how-can-i-get-all-the-rows-which-has-class-after-an-element-it-should-stop-when