# How can I get all the rows which has class after an element it should stop when it gets to a row where no class

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is fetch all the `rows` after the current row.
It should fetch all the rows after it until it stops having no particular class.
Example:

```
<tr class="clicked_el"></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr>
<tr></tr> //It should stop here
<tr class="getme></tr>
```

When I click on the `tr` with class clicked_el. I want to get all the 'tr' with `getme` class until the `tr` with no `getme` class.

I tried doing it with `nextAll` didnt know how to use filter with `nextUntil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(".clicked_el").nextUntil(":not(.getme)")`

This will return:

```
<tr class="clicked_el"></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr> <- This will be returned;
<tr class="getme"></tr> <- This will be returned;
<tr class="getme"></tr> <- This will be returned;
<tr class="getme"></tr> <- This will be returned;
<tr></tr>
<tr class="getme></tr>
```

**Demo**

```js
console.log($(".clicked_el").nextUntil(":not(.getme)").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clicked_el"></tr>
    <tr class="getme"></tr>
    <tr class="getme"></tr>
    <tr class="getme"></tr>
    <tr class="getme"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="getme"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Follow up question .. is there a way I can get the last `tr` with `getme` after that second last `tr`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method along with [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector) pseudo-class selector.

```
$('tr.clicked_el').nextUntil(':not(.getme)')
```

```js
$('tr.clicked_el').nextUntil(':not(.getme)').html('<td>selected<td>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
<tr class="clicked_el"></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr class="getme"></tr>
</table>
```

---

From jQuery [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)  docs :

> Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector.

Comment: Follow up question .. is there a way I can get the last `tr` with `getme` after that second last `tr`

Comment: @reyyoung $('tr.clicked_el tr:last')